# Arduino Mega2560 Hardware ID

Tags: arduino-mega

Do all Arduino Mega2560's have the same VID/PID identification numbers when seen by a PC as a device? I am planning on designing I specific driver to work with the 2560 and wondering if I will be able to use the same driver for multiple Arduino. Can anyone confirm this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

VIP/PID is realized by Atmega16u2 driver which implements USB device driver. Probably all revisions of *Arduino Atmega2560*s has implicitely the same VID/PID. Each piece has unique serial number. But you can upload own firmware into 16u2 to modify USB as you wish (ideally using LUFA library). It's clean solution for production hardware because you cannot use Arduino VID because of USB rules.